# What's a word for something that's almost possible

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I know my question might sound stupid but I was wondering what would be a word for something that almost impossible yet possible so that it's still quite achievable but requires tremendous effort and time. My sentence goes like 
'' She was told she would never be able to walk again however she was certain that she _____ would walk again

Comment: David, could you supply as many words as necessary to fill in the blank in your sentence? It seems that you want a one-word substitute for a phrase, but that phrase isn't "almost impossible yet possible so that it's still quite achievable but requires tremendous effort and time."

Comment: Being less flippant, describing something as *highly unlikely* could be enough. Terms like *miraculous recovery* and *astonishing success* are often used the describe the somewhat-unexpected outcomes.

Comment: 'Against all the odds' is a phrase that would be used by some.

Answer (score 2):

Although they doubted she would ever walk again, she was determined to overcome the insurmountable odds. She will walk again.